# Verbiage Must Be Updated

Tags: bug, status-completed

From: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> What questions are off topic here?
>
> - "I need advice on...", "What should I do?", or "Which job should I take?"
>
>   - Questions looking for opinions on what to do but with no specific problem are suited for discussion boards (not a question/answer site) and generally will be closed on The Workplace as "**not constructive**." For information on how to write a good subjective question see here. Remember a real question has an answer, not just opinions or ideas.

Bug = 'Not Constructive' is no longer a close reason.

Comment: I personally like the "not constructive" close reason better.  "primarily opinion-based" is too clunky sounding.

Comment: @acolyte I agree, but "not constructive" wasn't clear to everyone (particularly people whose questions were closed as not constructive), and led to complaining and debates on metas. Having a simpler explanation (even if the wording isn't as nice) makes it a bit clearer why it's closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated it to use the **primarily opinion-based** close reason.

Comment: "Based" was misspelled as `basd`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Fixed.